# Como usar o SharedPreferences do Android neste caso?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Estou tentando salvar uma estado de exibição, onde quando aperta o botão do robo, aparece uma mensagem "True" e muda o icone para de uma pessoa e quando aperto a da pessoa volta para o icone de robo e tem uma mensagem de "false", gostaria de usar o SharedPreference para salvar o ultimo estado de exibição, gostaria de saber onde estou errando, segue o código abaixo:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView testeT;
    boolean valorBooleano = false;
    SharedPreferences preferences;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        testeT = findViewById(R.id.text_teste);
        testeT.setText(" " + valorBooleano);

        preferences = getSharedPreferences("minhapreferencia", MODE_PRIVATE);
        preferences.getBoolean("chave", valorBooleano);
        editor = preferences.edit();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        if (valorBooleano == false) {
            menu.findItem(R.id.man).setVisible(true);
            menu.findItem(R.id.robot).setVisible(false);
        } else {
            menu.findItem(R.id.man).setVisible(false);
            menu.findItem(R.id.robot).setVisible(true);
        }


        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case (R.id.man):
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
                testeT.setText(" " + valorBooleano);
                valorBooleano = true;
                break;
            case (R.id.robot):
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
                testeT.setText(" " + valorBooleano);
                valorBooleano = false;
                break;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (preferences.contains("chave")){
            editor.putBoolean("chave", valorBooleano);
            editor.commit();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: pelo que eu entendi aí, o valor valorBooleano é sempre falso. Certo?

Comment: Ah sim, eu estava fazendo uns testes, pois mesmo removendo essa condição de falso ele não funciona

Comment: Dá uma conferida na minha resposta, identifique só alguns problemas, se a resposta for útil para você, marque como respondida e/ou útil, se não ajudo me avisa que edito minha resposta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O erro que identifiquei é que você está inicializando valorBooleano como falso, e isso não altera ao longo do ciclo. Então o que você precisa fazer é alterar a inicialização do seu valorBooleano e o seu onCreate para assim:

```
//apenas declare a variavel
boolean valorBooleano;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    testeT = findViewById(R.id.text_teste);


    preferences = getSharedPreferences("minhapreferencia", MODE_PRIVATE);
    //aqui o valorBooleano é incializado com a sharedpreferences, se não possuir valor atribuido a ela, então retornará false;
    valorBooleano = preferences.getBoolean("chave", false);
    //agora que o valorBooleano tá inicializado pode enviar o valor dele para o TextView
    testeT.setText(" " + valorBooleano);
    editor = preferences.edit();
}
```

Acredito que apenas essas 3 modificações já fará o que você deseja. Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Cara Funcionou!!!!!